# How to deselect lisboxitem in mvvmlight?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, mvvm-light

I had a quick question on working with listboxes in WP7 using MVVM Light. Basically before I was using MVVM all I had to do was set the SelectedIndex to -1 inside of the OnNavigatedTo event when the page was navigated to. Then inside of the SelectionChanged event I would check if the SelectedIndex was equal to -1 and if so I would ignore it. The reason I did this was just in case the user wanted to select the same item again when they came back to the page.

Now with MVVM (MVVM Light) I'm binding the event to a command, which takes care of the first part. But now I'm stuck because I don't know how to set the SelectedIndex to -1 from the ViewModel which prevents the user from selecting the same item again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `SelectedItem` property on your viewmodel, then do a two-way between the `SelectedItem` viewmodel property and the `SelectedItem` property on your `ListBox`. Then you can update it with whatever value you want when your `Command` fires and the result will propagate back to your `ListBox`.

Comment: Excellent question--not sure. If it does, you should be able to just exit early after checking the value of `SelectedItem`.

Comment: I'm wondering if setting the SelectedItem property your talking about to null when they navigate will fix the problem. One second.

Answer (score 2):

An even better solution is to not use the selection event to trigger a navigation. Use the tap event of the indivdual item instead.
This also avoids issues of accidental navigation when scrolling.

Comment: So you would set the tap event inside of the ItemTemplate. I'm guessing I would just pass the item as a command parameter then?